# codeigniter where() postgresql

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql

What is the format in codeigniter

```
SELECT seq,
       code,
       discipline, 
       bacc 
  FROM "psced-disc" p 
       JOIN table2 t 
            ON p.code=t.psced_id 
 WHERE t.tableID=table2;
```

I already tried this and its working but without the WHERE clause

```
$this->db->select('seq, code, discipline,bacc');
$this->db->from('psced-disc p');
$this->db->join('table2 t', 'p.code=t.psced_id');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

I want to add the **WHERE t.tableID=table2;**

Can anyone help me with this. I'm getting stuck at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
$this->db->select('seq, code, discipline,bacc');
$this->db->from('psced-disc p');
$this->db->join('table2 t', 'p.code=t.psced_id');
$this->db->where(array("t.tableID"=>"table2")); // or $this->db->where("t.tableID = 'table2'");
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Comment: Haha. That was quick. Thanks for the answer. I can't believe its so simple. I cant understand ACTIVE RECORD for codeigniter for  $this->db->where('name', $name); . I dont understand their sample. By the way I put $this->db->where("t.tableID = 'table2'"); and it is correct. Thanks again.

Comment: refer http://www.ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html   for more details about active records.